# Build MonoDevelop on Debian/Jessie using Mono 4.3.3

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, monodevelop

I'am trying to build MonoDevelop(master branch) on my Debian/Jessie box.
So far I managed to get it compiled, but it shows me 5 errors and 1 warning.

```
Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/home/max/monodevelop/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/max/monodevelop/main/external/RefactoringEssentials/RefactoringEssentials/RefactoringEssentials.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->

 /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.

Errors:

/home/max/monodevelop/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/max/monodevelop/main/src/addins/NUnit/NUnitRunner/NUnitRunner.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

NUnitTestRunner.cs(105,44): error CS0103: The name `LoggingThreshold' does not exist in the current context
NUnitTestRunner.cs(105,14): error CS1501: No overload for method `Run' takes `4' arguments
NUnitTestRunner.cs(124,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ParameterizedMethodSuite' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
NUnitTestRunner.cs(124,25): error CS0150: A constant value is expected

/home/max/monodevelop/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/max/monodevelop/main/external/RefactoringEssentials/RefactoringEssentials/RefactoringEssentials.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->

/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.

 1 Warning(s)
 5 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:07.6677160
Makefile:1086: recipe for target 'sln_build' failed
make[2]: *** [sln_build] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/max/monodevelop/main'
Makefile:645: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/max/monodevelop/main'
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I suggest that it has something to do with nunit which shipps with mono and PCL Reference Assemblies which are not installed. I know MS released PCL Reference Assemblies as an installer, but I can't install them on my linux box. Because its an .NET needed msi installer or sort of.

Comment: You need the Mono Development Kit (MDK) not the runtime, it will install the PCL targets

Comment: You need the `referenceassemblies-pcl` package, see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage for details

Comment: Thanks. I read the usage. I build mono from git and did not install the mono-package for debian/jessie because it is outdated. Is this an option https://github.com/directhex/xamarin-referenceassemblies-pcl?

Comment: I used the link above and it solved my problem.
I adjusted the control file and excluded the dependencie to mono-xbuild build the debian package and installed it using dpkg -i.

Comment: @maxpa1n87 post the solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to download

http://github.com/directhex/xamarin-referenceassemblies-pcl

using git. Adjust the control file under debian/ directory not depending on

`mono-xbuild`

Build the debian package using

`debuild -i -us -uc -b`

then installing the package using

`dpkg -i <package>`

What the installation does is to copy the PCL reference assemblies to

`/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable`.

After this compiling MonoDevelop does not show error about missing PCL reference assemblies. Hope that helps anyone trying to build latest MonoDevelop.